# Use one shape for last element, another for all others in chart

Tags: python, altair

Is there a way in Altair to use one shape for all the elements in a dataframe but the last? I have data columns and a category column. I'd like all but one of the categories to plot with a circle and one category to plot with a diamond.

I understand how to set shape and color ranges, but I don't understand how to set them conditionally based on the data, just the order and values of the shapes/colors

This is a simplified example:

```py
myData = {'category':['Cat 1','Cat 2','Cat 3'], 
          'valueX':['10','20','30'], 
          'valueY':['10','20','30']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=myData)

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
  x = 'valueX',
  y = 'valueY',
  shape = alt.Shape('category', scale=alt.Scale(range=['circle','diamond']))
)
```

This just alternates between the circle and diamond. How do I have my first two categories use the circle and 'Cat 3' use the diamond?

Comment: I experimented by adding a second circle in the shape line, eg: ```shape = alt.Shape('category', scale=alt.Scale(range=['circle','circle','diamond']))``` and that works. But what if I don't know how many categories I'll have until I read in my data? I could count the unique categories and create a list of 'circle'...<n>...'diamond' but that seems like an inelegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

The scale property allow you to map a `domain` to a `range`, where the `domain` specifies input values, and the `range` specifies the visual properties to which the domain is mapped. If you want multiple domain values to map to the same range value, it can be done like this:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
  x = 'valueX',
  y = 'valueY',
  shape = alt.Shape('category',
    scale=alt.Scale(
      domain=['Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3'],
      range=['circle', 'circle', 'diamond']
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that according to grammar of `altair`, the shape encoding will assign a new shape to every category. The purpose of the encoding is to distinguish between categories, so it makes sense to assign each category a new shape.

When you want to encode many categories using only two shapes, you are losing information, and this goes again the purpose of encodings in `altair`.

So, if you would like to have the first two categories be a circle, and the last be a diamond, you can make another column in your dataset that explicitly encodes this.

This is a data issue (i.e., addressed using `pandas`) rather than being an issue with `altair`.

In the example code below, I named the new column `shape`

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

myData = {'category':['Cat 1','Cat 2','Cat 3'],
          'shape':['c','c','d'],
          'valueX':['10','20','30'], 
          'valueY':['10','20','30']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=myData)

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
  x = 'valueX',
  y = 'valueY',
  shape = alt.Shape('shape', scale=alt.Scale(range=['circle','diamond']))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I understand that my explanation sort of violates the point of having shapes. I guess I should have gone into more detail about what I'm actually trying to do. I'm recreating a report our data analytics guy did by hand, and he used both color and shape on his plot. The color is the truly unique value, with all but one type of data being in different colored circles. The diamond was to highlight, for lack of a better term, out of spec data points to help them stand out a little better. I think I have a good working solution now. Thanks everyone.